# How do I Align Header on the same line using display?

Tags: html, css, display, text-align

I aligned the objects using `display: flex;` Now I have tried to put the header on the same line using `text-align: justify;` and `display: block;`, but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong. Can someone please help with this?

```css
.pos-container {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.pos-info {
  display: inline-flex;
  float: left;
}

.pos-info: before {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #045d71;
  content: " ";
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pos-image {
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 47%;
  height: 50%;
}

.pos-container i {
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #07a0c3;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: block;
}

.pos-info h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 110%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  float: left;
  column-width: auto;
}

.pos-content {
  display: flex;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: 69px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -118px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.pos-content: after {
  display: block;
  height: 0.1px;
  background-color: #045d71;
  content: " ";
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="pos-container">
    <li class="pos-info">
      <img class="pos-image" src="resources/img/cashier2.jpg" alt="pos picture">
      <i class="ion-arrow-left-b"></i>
      <h3>POS Software</h3>
      <p class="pos-content">We offer a payment solution which functions on the cloud. It gives you access to your inventory, expenses, sales and operations from wherever you are located. It is designed for simplicity, so your employees won’t need any special training to use
        the software. In case of a bad connection to the internet, the payment system will still work normally and would update every captured payment and transaction, once the connection is restored. A cheap and affordable solution for any type of restaurant,
        bar or lounge with available payment plans.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: your html structure completly is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

h2 {
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" />
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @lightmyfire, tried this and still doesn't work for me. Might be doing something wrong